# How do I solve $x^2 + y^2 + xy = z$ for $y$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How do I solve the following equation for $x$ or $y$ (does not matter because you can swap them):

$$
x^2+y^2+xy=z
$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Can you please describe some of your thoughts and the things you've tried in order for us to provide better guidance? Regards

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To solve for $x$, say, just consider $y$ and $z$ as constants, and use the usual formula for the quadratic equation.

Comment: Oh yes of course, no idea why that did not came to mind.

Comment: @Jori, don't worry, it happens quite often to most of us (including Yours Truly).

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Complete the square in $x$ or $y$. This approach is how you prove the quadratic formula.

**Added:**

$$x^2+y^2+xy=z \implies  \left(x+\frac{y}{2}\right)^2=z-\frac{3}{4} y^2 \implies \dots. $$

Comment: ...so we'll get something like $(x-y)^2+3xy-z=0$, which is even harder to solve

Comment: I like this approach too. Thanks for the clarification, as you can see your comment confused a little. Vote up when I reach 15 haha.